# LATEX skips numbers in numbering when putting several figures in the same figure environment

Tags: latex, figure

Here are the package I am using:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{SIunits} 
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
\bibliographystyle{approve}
```

In order to put two figures next to each other, using the full width of the page even with the twocolumn option, I use this syntax:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mfploglog_A.eps}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mfploglog.eps}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{XXX}\protect\label{Eloglog}
\end{figure*}
```

The probleme is that using this the numbering is incorrect. For each figure, a number is skipped as if the subfigure environment was counting as one figure. For example if I put just this figure in my code, it is going to be labeled as figure number 2.

Does someone already encountered this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (or [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)) with [`revtex4-1`](http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1). You'll note in the `.log` that there are compatibility issues between the package and the class. Instead, place the two images side-by-side in the same `figure*` *without* using a `subfigure` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,preprintnumbers]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3333\linewidth]{example-image-a} \qquad
  \includegraphics[width=.3333\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{XXX}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

---

If you wish to add captions to the sub-figures, set the construction inside a `tabular` and enumerate them manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,preprintnumbers]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c @{\qquad} c }
    \includegraphics[width=.3333\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.3333\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
    \small (a) Left & \small (b) Right
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{XXX}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But what if you want captions on each subfigure?  I have 3 figures, each with subfigures.  They appear in my document as Figures 1, 3, and 5, instead of Figures 1, 2, and 3.